# how to create localization in visual web developer 2010

Tags: asp.net, localization, visual-web-developer-2010

I need help how to create localization in visual web developer 2010? If someone know good tutorial or other something useful how to create it.
 I tried to create but there is no generate local resources option in the tools menu. I read few posts that developer couldn't support this option. So, if someone could help me by advice what to do? tnx in advance

Comment: I didn't say that I tried to create but there is no generate local resources option in the tools menu. A read few posts that developer couldn't support this option. So, if someone could help me by advice what to do? tnx in advance

Comment: you know you can edit the question?

Comment: if someone know please help me?